# Python string insertion

Tags: python, insertion

I remember learning that there is a simple way to insert string segments into other strings quite easily in Python, but I don't remember how it's done. For example, let's say I'm editing HTML with Python and it looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <b>Hello, World!</b>
  <b>%</b>
</html>
```

So, let's say this HTML code is stored in a variable called html. Now, let's say that I want to manipulate this code and enter the following string "My name is Bob" instead of the % in the second b tag.

If anybody knows what I am talking about, please answer, it is a really cool feature that I would like to use. Thank you!

Comment: ["String formatting"](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Answer (score 2):

You can append % and a tuple of values:

```
name = "Bob"
html = "Hello, %s" % (name)
```

Or name the placeholders and use a dictionary:

```
html = "Hello, %(name)s" % { name: name }
```

Or use [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples)

```
html = "Hello, {0}".format("name")
```

All three result in a string `Hello, Bob`.

You can also leave a string unbound like this

```
html = "Hello, %s"
```

and then bind the placeholder whenever necessary

```
print html
>>> Hello, %s
for name in ["John", "Bob", "Alice"]:
    print html % name
>>> Hello, John
>>> Hello, Bob
>>> Hello, Alice
```

Comment: Insertion string ordinals for .format() start at 0, so that example should be `html = "Hello, {0}".format("name")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
html='''<html>
  <b>Hello, World!</b>
  <b>%s</b>
</html>''' % "My name is Bob"
```

It is simple string formatting. You can also use the following (you can use `{variable}` multiple times to insert it in multiple places):

```
html='''<html>
  <b>Hello, World!</b>
  <b>{variable}</b>
</html>'''.format(variable="My name is Bob")
```

*or* you can use the following if you want to replace EVERY "%" in that:

```
html='''<html>
  <b>Hello, World!</b>
  <b>%</b>
</html>'''.replace('%','Hello my name is Bob')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way that use string template

there is a sample code

```
import string

htmlTemplate = string.Template(
"""
<html>
<b>Hello, World!</b>
<b>$variable</b>
</html>
""")

print htmlTemplate.substitute(dict(variable="This is the string template"))
```

you can define your variable in template string with $